# After sql server 2008 silent install log-in fails

Tags: sql-server-2008, command-prompt, silent-installer

have the following command to install sql using CMD prompt.

> C:\SQL Server 2008\setup.exe" /QS /INDICATEPROGRESS /ACTION=Install
>   /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck
>   /FEATURES=SQL,RS,BIDS,Conn,BC,SDK,BOL,SSMS,ADV_SSMS,SNAC_SDK,OCS
>   /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLServer /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
>   /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Manual /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
>   /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /ASSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
>   /ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /RSSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
>   /RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /ISSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
>   /ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Disabled
>   /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=test /RSINSTALLMODE=DefaultNativeMode
>   /ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

The installation goes fine and all the required services are installed.

the problem i have is when i try to log-in to the installed instance through management studio i get "Server Name: "

Error Number: 18456. ??

how can i reassign parameter values so that i will be able to login after install

Answer (score 0):

You should use .\SQLEXPRESS as server name and windows authentication. To access sql from your PC name the follow this tutorial. [Click Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i'm trying to do a full install and not a express install